# Could a planet, moon, or comet having a high concentration of a certain metal disrupt radio transmission?

Tags: communication, comet, mining, radio-communication

I have been researching how metals affect radio transmission but have not found anything conclusive to the specific scope about planet density if it is mostly metal.

One of the posts that I found any info on was this page
http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/2002-03/1015162213.Eg.r.html

I have also found that gravity does affect wireless radio transmission. 
http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r13178764-Are-wireless-transmissions-affected-by-gravity-

But what would it take to entirely prevent transmissions in our current radio systems used by our space travel agencies, and what modifications would need to be made to prevent such losses in transmission should we encounter such a situation?

**Background (what prompted me to ask)**
I had a dream that i piloted a small craft to a comet to mine for metal. But its magnetism disrupted our radio communication. So I am wondering if this could really be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnetic field of the Earth isn't just based on the quantity of iron in the core. The metal has to be liquid and rotating to cause a magnetic field. This rotation is usually a product of the Coriolis effect, and I would suppose a very short day on the planet/comet would increase the magnetic field strength. It comes down to a comet just not being large enough, or more accurately not being massive enough, for the core to be molten.

Also this is your second 'I dreamt... Would this work' question. If you have a different reason for asking more directed answer could br shared. For example if you're a writer, we could point you towards the worldbuilding stack exchange site.

Comment: Ok so likely the answer is that in most cases radio transmission would be fine? I am not a sci-fi writer though, i was asking out of curiosity.

Comment: @JGallardo for the most part you'd struggle to find a planet with a strong enough magnetic field, let alone a comet. If you start looking into transmission through the comet that's a different question!

Comment: I'm tempted to down-vote. Unless I misunderstand your answer ; the first two sentences convey the assumption an iron core - or some significant quantity of molten iron, and spin constitute a necessary precondition. 

Jupiter is possessed of the strongest magnetosphere in the System, yet it's core is theoretically metallized hydrogen - rather than iron... To be honest, molten metallic hydrogen